# What is the similarity between an actual riffle shuffle and a riffle shuffle permutation?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A riffle shuffle permutation is sometimes cited as the mathematical equivalent of a riffle shuffle in real life, but I'm having a hard time understanding the similarity between the two.

In real life, a riffle shuffle cuts the ordered deck in two, then interleaves the two decks by adding a card from the bottom of each deck to the top of the (soon-to-be) shuffled deck.

For instance, starting with $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8$, cut into $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ and $6, 7, 8$, we might get $1, 6, 2, 3, 7, 4, 8, 5$.

In mathematics, the riffle shuffle permutation is a permutation that turns an ordered sequence into two consecutive ordered sequences.

For instance, starting with $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8$, we might get $1, 4, 7, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8$.

The real-life riffle shuffle, unless I'm misinterpreting the link between the two, will never yield a mathematical riffle shuffle permutation unless we do not interleave the two cut decks at all. On the other hand, the mathematical riffle shuffle looks more similar to a kind of "reverse" riffle shuffle, where you extract two decks which are interleaved from the initial ordered deck, then stack them on top of eachother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, card 1 ended up in position 1 after the shuffle, card 2 ended up in position 3, card 3 in position 4, card 4 in position 6, etc., so the riffle shuffle permutation $\pi$ corresponding to that shuffle is
$$
\begin{aligned}
\pi(1) = 1 \\
\pi(2) = 3 \\
\pi(3) = 4 \\
\pi(4) = 6 \\
\pi(5) = 8 \\
\\
\pi(6) = 2 \\
\pi(7) = 5 \\
\pi(8) = 7
\end{aligned}
$$
with two increasing sequences giving the positions of cards 1 to 5 and of cards 6 to 8, respectively.